# scrollTop on function call animate multiple

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, jquery-animate

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/Borisko/604rLvbc/38/

I want add animation (delay, what ever, make it nice) to scrolTop:

```
 $div.scrollTop(fixpos);
```

after adding animation, everything broke, and **scrolling** goes **multiple times**.

it there any way to make scrollTop animation run just once (like without animation)

Comment: So, what you actually want? An animation functionality?

Comment: if you scroll element as it is, everything working as I want. (like scroling etc, ) NOW i want to add animation to scrollTop - so yes animation functionality - making scrolling animated, but still ONE step BY step = not go to test 4 or 6 on first scroll, animation is "called" multiple time)

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong here. I tried first scroll but it worked fine. I mean if you scroll fast then mousewheel will of course get called multiple times

Comment: ok again. if u run this code - its ok. --- but i wanna add animation to  $div.scrollTop(fixpos); - if u add animation, the functionality stop, and code doesnt work - animation on one scroll goes multiple times to wrong element... but without animation scroll goes right just one step.... so question is ho to animate scrollTop(fixpos); to achieve just one scroll step like without animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I can't be sure about the reason behind this - *if u add animation, the functionality stop, and code doesnt work - animation on one scroll goes multiple times to wrong element* - but this is what I think is happening here : the scrollTop() value is still not updated when we assign value to `pos`

```
var pos = $div.scrollTop();
```

So instead before animating I have stored `scrollTop` value in a global variable `valuePos` and then set that value to `pos` on next scroll. I have initialized `valuePos` with `scrollTop`.

```
var valuePos = $("#target").scrollTop();
```

If you scroll fast the animation will work but with a slight delay as we are calling multiple `animate` here. I have used `.stop()` just before `animate` call so that animation won't lag too much.

Please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/dpn5mrjy/).

Comment: as you overide math function  

var fixpos = Math.floor(nextPos / 30.0) * 30;
valuePos = fixpos;

this causing "actual" div to be at wrong place from top sometimes when wrong pixel combination show.

anyway thx for reply, will try to update your code.

Comment: here is it fixed to be always in right place, thank you
http://jsfiddle.net/Borisko/9Lp75w6c/3/

Comment: Oh I see that in order to avoid that issue, you have adjusted value of `pos`. Does the trick for now.